# Using VBA copying from one master workbook to other multiple workbooks in a folder based on file names provided in Master Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Pretty new to this hence taking it as challenge. I have a master sheet in which Column A have all the file names( complete file name with .xls extensions). I need to copy data of column b in this sheet and paste it in all the files in a particular folder in a particular tab. There can be multiple items for one name. Sample Data

```
Australia.xlsx  XX
Austria.xlsx    YY
Austria.xlsx    DD
Belgium.xlsx    OO
Brazil.xlsx     MM
Brazil.xlsx     NN
```

Here is the code i tried to write:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim Country As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    k = 2
    For i = 2 To 50

        Windows("try 1 split to combines").Activate
        Country = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Workbooks("try 1 split to combines").Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(i, i + 1)).Copy

        Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\abhayl.INDIA\Desktop\For Primary Team\For Primary Team\" & Country & " "
        'Workbooks("Name").Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Specific Questions").Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Specific Questions").Cells(k, 2).xlPasteValues
        finalrow2 = 42 + k
        k = finalrow2 + 1
        Workbooks(Country).Sheets("Specific Questions").Activate
        Workbooks(Country).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is pretty basic but need some improving, can anyone help me out to better rewrite this code?

Comment: Will changing the range help. Dynamic range?

Comment: Also, you need to explicitly declare what sheet you want to reference when using `Range()`, `Cells()`, `Rows()`, `Columns()`, etc.  For example, your `.Copy` line needs the worksheet you expect the `Cells(i,i+1)` to be on.  Also, if this works, and you just want someone to make it any better, this is more suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).